# Struggling with for-loop and mutate in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am trying to wrap my head around R, and I'm sure I'm doing something silly.

I have a dataframe that includes 30 brands (whose names I have separately in a list called "brands") and a list of new names that I wish to insert into the dataframe (called "known brands").

I am trying to populate the results of an if statement within new columns in an R dataframe (using the names within "known brands), but this keeps on generating an error message (unexpected '{' in "{")

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong - here's my code:

```
for(i in 1:length(brands)){
  plot1a_df <- plot1a_df %>% mutate(known_brands[i] = ifelse(brands[i] >1, 1, 0))
}
```

To illustrate with data (assume 3 x2 columns):

plot1a_df = data.frame(brands = c(1,0,2), Misc = c(0,0,0))

The idea is to end up with a third column ("known_brands") with c(0,0,1)

Comment: Please add a reproducible example of your data. `dput()` usually is enough to go on.

Comment: You are missing one `)` parentheses before the `}`

Comment: RLave, Jozef, Imran: Thanks for your help to date. I've edited my code to consider your comments. Sadly what's been said so far does not work. The challenge I have is in getting a for-loop to run within dplyr (mutate in this case)

Answer (score 0):

To add a logical column with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
plot1a_df %>% mutate(is_brand_known = brands %in% brand_list)
```

Another example with *iris* dataset.

```
species_list = c('setosa')
iris %>% mutate(is_setosa = Species %in% species_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 1:30){
  plot1a_df[, known_cols[i]] <- ifelse(plot1a_df[,brands[i]] >1, 1, 0)
  print(plot1a_df[, known_cols[i]])
}
```

Found my solution could be achieved without mutate - although, still wonder if it is possible to combine for loops within dplyr (realise there's a lot of commentary on here, but nothing at a high level (for this simpleton to understand at least!)